# alinear de forma dinamica una columna de datatables (Jquery)

Tags: datatables

tengo una tabla de datatable  en la cual muestro unas columnas u otras dependiendo de una variable. El problema es que al cambiar el numero de columnas, no puedo hacer la alineación de columnas con el target.

```
"columnDefs": [
                {className: "dt-body-right","targets": [3,10,11]},

            ],
```

Como se podría alinear una columna por ejemplo por su nombre?

```
"columns": [  {
                    "data": "name"
                }, {
                    "data": "fch_fin_prevista"
                }, ],
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esta estructura:

```
columnDefs': [
  {
      "targets": 0, // Tu primera columna
      "className": "dt-body-right",
      "width": "4%"
 },
 {
      "targets": 2,
      "className": "dt-body-right",
 }],
```

Comment: Hola david, el problema es que si numero de columnas cambia, el target ya no me vale. En numero de columnas me va a cambiar de forma dinamica

Comment: Una pregunta, cuando dices "alineación de columnas" quieres decir a nivel de ccs? osea aplicarle el css?

Comment: me refiero no a la cabecera, al dato, imagina una columna que sea coche y que tengo 20 modelos. la cabecera ya la alineo yo en html, es la columna de datos la que quiero alinear

Comment: ok perfecto, lo hago localmente y te lo posteo editando mi respuesta

Comment: David, acabo de comprobar que aunque el numero de columnas cambié por que yo las haga invisibles, datatable sigue manteniendo el orden de estas. Disculpa las molestias

Comment: No se preocupe, que bueno que resolviera